# IF Statement problems

Tags: excel, if-statement

In one column in a spreadsheet, I have values: **A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K** :

```
A in rows 1-4,
B in rows 5-9,
C in rows 10-19,
D in rows 20-49,
E in rows 50-99,
F in rows 100-249,
G in rows 250-499,
H in rows 500-999,
I in rows 1,000-4,999,
J in rows 5,000-9,999,
K in rows 10,000+
```

I am using the following function:

```
=IF(OR(G2={""}), "", IF(OR(G2={"A"}), "1-4", ""), IF(OR(G2={"B"}), "5-9", ""), IF(OR(G2={"C"}), "10-19", ""), IF(OR(G2={"D"}), "20-49", ""), IF(OR(G2={"E"}), "50-99", ""), IF(OR(G2={"F"}), "100-249", ""), IF(OR(G2={"G"}), "250-499", ""), IF(OR(G2={"H"}), "500-999", ""), IF(OR(G2={"I"}), "1000-4999", ""), IF(OR(G2={"J"}), "5000-9999", ""), IF(OR(G2={"K"}), "10000", ""))
```

I am getting an error that states "You have entered too many arguments for this function".
Where am I failing?

When I run the following, I do not receive an error:

```
=IF(OR(G2={""}), "", IF(OR(G2={"A"}), "1-4", ""))
```

But the moment I add another line like the following:

```
=IF(OR(G2={""}), "", IF(OR(G2={"A"}), "1-4", ""), IF(OR(G2={"B"}), "5-9", ""))
```

I get the error.

How can I avoid this error?

Comment: Yes, use an ordered table of letters with values, and use VLOOKUP's natural "next best" feature, which looks for a specific value but stops when that value has been exceeded in an ordered list.

Answer (score 2):

The `IF()` syntax is

```
=if(condition, true result, false result)
```

You don't have that. You're doing

```
=if(condition, true result, false result, other result 1, other result 2, etc...)
```

which is a syntax error. If you want to chain IF()s like that, you'd need somethign like

```
   =if(condition, true result, IF(othercondition, true result, IF(...)))
      1                          2                               3   321
```

Note the bracket numbering.

Answer (score 1):

No need for the `OR` in your example, and you need to get rid of the `,""` when you include another `IF` :

```
=IF(G2={""}, "", IF(G2={"A"}, "1-4", IF(G2={"B"}, "5-9", "")))
```

And the whole thing (you did the same error after the test for B) :

```
=IF(G2={""},"",IF(G2={"A"},"1-4",IF(G2={"B"},"5-9",IF(G2={"C"},"10-19",IF(G2={"D"},"20-49",IF(G2={"E"},"50-99",IF(G2={"F"},"100-249",IF(G2={"G"},"250-499", IF(G2={"H"},"500-999" ,IF(G2={"I"},"1000-4999" ,IF(G2={"J"},"5000-9999", IF(G2={"K"},"10000",""))))))))))))
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I tried your logic but still get the same error message when I add the following: =IF(G2={""},"",IF(G2={"A"},"1-4",IF(G2={"B"},"5-9","",IF(G2={"C"},"10-19","",IF(G2={"D"},"20-49","",IF(G2={"E"},"50-99","",IF(G2={"F"},"10-249","",IF(G2={"G"},"250-499","",IF(G2={"H"},"500-999","",IF(G2={"I"},"1000-4999","",IF(G2={"J"},"5000-9999","",IF(G2={"H"},"10000","")))

Comment: @pnuts : Yup, there should have been 12, I corrected that also in my answer

Comment: @pnuts : Sorry for the parenthesis misunderstanding. Thx for pointing out the ghost characters (freaking line returns...) and the `H` instead of the `K`. I corrected all of that!

Comment: @pnuts : Yup, that's why I upvoted MarcB's answer! ;) Could include it in mine, but I don't really like plagia so I'll do it if my answer get accepted! Thx for the +1!

Answer (score 0):

You have too many arguments in your first `IF` statement. Try something like this

```
=IF(OR(G2={""}), "", IF(OR(G2={"A"}), "1-4", IF(OR(G2={"B"}), "5-9", "")))
```

Comment: SOLVED!! Thanks a million Matt!